# Show only 2 numbers after percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem where when i run the following query I get "PercentageDifference" as 99.253731343283500 all i really want to show is 99.25 but no amount fiddling seems to get it any lower or results in an error:

```
select PlannedMonthName
     , CountOfPlannedVisits
     , CountOfPlannedVisitsClosed
     , CONVERT( DECIMAL(12,2), nullif(CountOfPlannedVisitsClosed, 0) ) 
       / CONVERT( DECIMAL(12,2), nullif(CountOfPlannedVisits, 0) )
       * 100 AS PercentageDifference
```

Comment: have you tried convert to Decimal(18,2) also the result of division?

Comment: If you are using MySQL why is this also tagged as tsql?

Comment: Yes, Tried (18,2) and still get the same result!

Comment: trunc or Round may meet your need depending if you want to round up or down http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-round-numbers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round` function as follows:

```
select PlannedMonthName
     , CountOfPlannedVisits
     , CountOfPlannedVisitsClosed
     , round( ( CONVERT( DECIMAL(12,2), nullif(CountOfPlannedVisitsClosed, 0) ) 
                / CONVERT( DECIMAL(12,2), nullif(CountOfPlannedVisits, 0) )
                * 100 
               ), 2) AS PercentageDifference
```

**TRUNCATE(X,D)** can be used as well :

It returns the number X, truncated to D decimal places. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part. D can be negative to cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X to become zero.

Comment: Thanks Ahsan, That appears to work but the result is now 99.250000000000000. Any suggestion as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `FORMAT` function. It converts numbers to a string with a fixed number of digits after the decimal point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: But this will return a string as a result, not sure if that's what op wants

Comment: @Lamak, looking at the response to Ahsan's answer, string conversion seems to be what the OP is looking for.